# Making scatter plot with ggplot2 leads to memory allocation issue

Tags: r, memory-management, ggplot2

(R beginner here...) I have a dataset like:

```
> head(q)
            Date Time System User
1 2011-10-01 00:00:01   12.4  4.6
2 2011-10-01 01:00:02   27.4  1.8
3 2011-10-01 02:00:01   15.2  1.0
4 2011-10-01 03:00:01   19.8  2.4
5 2011-10-01 04:00:02   19.2  3.4
6 2011-10-01 05:00:01   17.8  1.8
> nrow(q)
[1] 2207
```

Where 'Date Time' was formed from raw csv data with as.POSIXct(...)
But when I try a plot with more than 1300 rows:

```
> qplot(q$'Date Time',q$'User');dev.off()
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.8 Gb
```

And it's the same with:

```
> ggplot(q,aes(q$'Date Time',q$'User'))+geom_point(); dev.off()
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.8 Gb
```

What can I do to make it work? I want a scatter of system performance metrics which is spread over three months - the data is hourly so theres about 2200 rows.

Comment: I was running this inside an interactive "R" session and it seems if I run this from a script with Rscript I do not have the problem at all. I have a lot to learn about R memory management it seems :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the aes function wrong. You use:

```
ggplot(q,aes(q$'Date Time',q$'User'))+geom_point()
```

while the correct would be:

```
ggplot(q,aes_string(x = 'Date Time', y = 'User')) + geom_point()
```

There is no need to feed a vector of data to aes. You could try to see if it helps.
In addition, 
A good tip is also to use `ggsave` to save your ggplot's to file.

Comment: The op already told us that his problem was fixed, 2200 points already seemed a small amount of points for 9.8 gb. I`ll leave the answer as a generak strategy for plotting many points.

Comment: You were spot on with my misunderstanding of aes - it made all the difference in the interactive session - seems aes with the double vector input was going nuts!. And thanks for mentioning ggsave.

Comment: I've just gone back to this and the problem still exists in a fresh session / Rscript when using qplot instead of ggplot. I've used melt to produce a reduced data.frame called cpu, but "qplot(dt,value,data=cpu,geom="line",group=variable)" still fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example? You could either do this by uploading the dataset somewhere or by create a mockup dataset with random numbers and factors.